# Proper alignment of figures between desired text lines

Tags: floats

Using the following latex commands, i have been able to run the latex file, but i am unable to include these figures between desired text lines. Almost all the figures are being sequentially arranged(which is not desirable) skipping the text lines between them.This is my latex file:

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics[height=6.6em]{example-image} 
\caption{An example image\label{eximg}} \end{figure} 
Some text, see Figure \ref{eximg}.
\end{document}
```

How to include these figures between desired text lines?

Comment: The only purpose of `figure` is to allow the content to move. Your last question (where that document comes from) was already a duplicate but I answered as you were new but this really is the most common question of all, I'll link you to duplicates.

Comment: @David Carlisle, yes it is duplicate text from your answer to my previous question i was trying to tag you but couldn't find options to do so. The problem is quite different here please help me

Comment: the question is different to your first question, but identical to the one I linked to, also you might want to look at the first two high vote answers on floats at this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/floats?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks a lot